# How to solve a spool space error with rank () over partition by SQL optimising?

Tags: teradata, rank, spool

I have a table holding information about contacts made to many different customers in the format

> email_address | treatment_group | customer_id | contact_date |

I am trying to add a column that looks at each distinct customer and numbers the contacts they've received from longest ago to most recent. I'm using this code:

```
explain create table db.responses_with_rank
as 
(  select a.*, 
          rank () over (partition by customer_id order by contact_date asc)as xrank
  from  db.responses_with_rank
) 
with data
primary index (email_address, treatment_group)
```

My query is spooling out. There is a primary index of email_address, treatment_group that leads to a skew factor of  1.1 and a secondary primary index on customer_id. I've collected statistics on both sets of indexes. The table is quite large - around 200M records. Is there something I can try to optimize this query?

Comment: What's the DDL of the source table? And how much spool do yo have? `select spoolspace from dbc.usersV where UserName = user;`

Comment: Btw, what's a *secondary primary index*? Statistics will not help in your case.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information to determine the cause of the error.
For start, please add the following to your question:

1. TD version (`select * from dbc.dbcinfo`)
2. Execution plan
3. The statistics collection commands you have used
4. customer_id top frequencies (`select top 10 customer_id,count(*) from db.responses_with_rank group by 1 order by 2 desc`)
5. Do you have wide text columns in your table?

P.s.
I strongly recommend to use `create multiset table` and not `create table`.

Comment: I looked at number 4 and found that a few customer_ids had way more rows that the rest. I excluded those customers which allowed me to make the primary key customer_id without skewing the table. This allowed the query to run.

Comment: My pleasure :-)

Comment: @Kristen since the answer was helpful, would you mind to mark this is a right answer? and if you like it you might also want to upvote

Comment: @Kristen: would you be so kind as to click the tick mark adjacent to this answer, if it helped you? This is how we thank people for assistance here.

Comment: @halfer, and  more important, people that reach this post will know that there is a solution